# Block specific user via telegram bot API

Tags: telegram, ddos

How can I block specific user so that my bot doesn't receive requests from this specific user?

I tried to check for the presence of a user in the database, but the bot is still falling down because there are too many requests. I would like to know if there is a function that will completely ignore those who are not in my database.